# App crashing when I declare an instance of STPPaymentCardTextField()

Tags: ios, swift3, stripe-payments

I have integrated stripe sdk and creating a variable as follows,

```
let paymentTextField = STPPaymentCardTextField()
```

But when I run the app, it is crashing with following error,

> [__NSCFConstantString stp_safeSubstringToIndex:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x10eab2290

Comment: make sure you're setting your publishable API Key before making the call ;)

Comment: thanks mate...you saved my day :)

Comment: cool . Welcome @Sanket Bhavsar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set your publishable API Key before making the call.